# How to use .htaccess for file rewriting .php on GCP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform

I have a .htaccess file which is rewriting all of my urls from `path/to/file.php` to just `path/to/file`.

I had this working locally on WAMP, and it also worked on a domain hosted by blacknight.

However, we are moving to Google Cloud Platform using Debian 9, and it does not work here at all. If I do not include the .php extension I will get a 404 error.

Below is my full .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^post/([^\/]+)/?$ post.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^payment/([^\/]+)/?$ payment.php?sub=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^player/([^\/]+)/?$ player.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 hour"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
    <filesmatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </filesmatch>
    <filesmatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, private"
    </filesmatch>
    <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, private"
    </filesmatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

What can I do to resolve this or is there another way of rewriting URLs in Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: Well, what http server is used in that new environment?

Comment: Are you 100% that you're using Apache and not Nginx (or any other web server) on GCP? htaccess are Apache config files. If you are using Apache, make sure that mod_rewrite is installed and enabled.

Comment: it's a LAMP server, just did `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and it says `Module rewrite already enabled`

Comment: If you do include the .php extension then does the url succeed?

Comment: @Gustavo yeah it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Apache server is enabled you should check if the AllowOverride directive is enabled as well (set to "All" or allowing specific options). Otherwise Apache will not consider the directives that you put there.

This should usually be placed in your Virtual server config file or the main one.

Here is an example:

```
<Directory "/path/from/where/you/serve/files">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

More info:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Thanks for your help, this sorted it, took my a while to figure it out cause i'm mainly frontend so apache config files scare the S*** outta me

Comment: @PaddyHallihan i am facing the same issue where we do this things in which file... please help me.

Comment: @vineetpal the apache config file is located at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf